# What is the new way to get the external IP and port number in Unity 2017.x?

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, ip, public, nat

In the old Unity (pre 5.1) there was the following method to get the external ip and port number:

```
//connect to some public URL
Network.Connect("some public URL");

//After connection I have the following fields populated:
NetworkPlayer.externalIP;
NetworkPlayer.externalPort;
```

But these are deprecated in the new versions of Unity, what is the new standard way of doing this?

EDIT: Clarification I am talking about the public IP (and maybe port number) as it's seen from the internet's point of view which is different then the local IP in a LAN because of NAT. In the end, what I'm trying to achieve is NAT traversal. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `NetworkManager.networkAddress` and `NetworkManager.networkPort`? Also, why do you need these?

Comment: `Network.externalIP` and `Network.externalPort` do not appear in *any* version that I can find.

Comment: @Draco18s you need a Network object to access those non static members. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NetworkPlayer-externalIP.html

Comment: @Programmer I don't think that will help me. Take a look at the NetworkManager source: https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/networking/src/78ca8544bbf4e87c310ce2a9a3fc33cdad2f9bb1/Runtime/NetworkManager.cs?at=5.3&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: @Sil No, you need a [*`NetworkPlayer`* object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NetworkPlayer.html). Not a [`Network` object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.html). And there was no way I would know that from your code because if your `Network` is an instance of a `NetworkPlayer`, it is ungodly badly named.

Comment: @Draco18s yes, you are right, I meant NetworkPlayer but NetworkPlayer is also from the old depricated Unity networking system.

Comment: From what I found out, it seams that NetworkPlayer is not depricated. Can anyone confirm this?